# Android web view zoom back issue, when user focus out from text field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

Here's the issue: Initial load of the page fits to the screen. When User click on any input field boxes, the page zooms and it doesn’t come back to its original. So I want to find out a way to zoom-out the page to fit it to the device screen back after the user focus out or hit enter key.

And I tried these setting and it didn't workout

```
setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
setSupportZoom(false);
setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
setusewideviewport(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your html:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

It's also a good idea to add the next settings to your webview.

```
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
```